# Hibernate Code for Query

Tags: hibernate

I found this Hibernate Criteria/Projection [tutorial](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/Hibernate-Criteria-Queries-in-Depth/2/) clear, concise and informative.

The author, A.P.Rajshekhar, says,

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM ORDER  HAVING PRICETOTAL>2000 GROUP BY ID
```

> Can be rewritten in Criteria query as follows:

```
List orders = session.createCriteria(Order.class)
     .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
      .add( Projections.count(“id”) )
       .add( Projections.groupProperty(“id”) )
     )
      .list();
```

However, where does the `HAVING PRICETOTAL>2000` show up in the Hibernate code? Is there a missing criterion (where clause in SQL) for this comparison?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You also need:

```
.add(Restrictions.gt("priceTotal", 2000))
```

assuming the name of the PRICETOTAL property on the Order class is indeed "priceTotal"